# Bootstrap 3 control div sizing hight and width

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, resize

I have a div that contains a checkbox and I like to make it double or more  in height from what it is now, so more checkboxes options will be shown

```css
.containerSelectBox {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-8 control-label"> Data Sources </label>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-control ">
      <input type="checkbox" /> This is checkbox <br />
      <input type="checkbox" /> This is checkbox <br />
      <input type="checkbox" /> This is checkbox <br />
      <input type="checkbox" /> This is checkbox <br />
      <input type="checkbox" /> This is checkbox <br />
      <input type="checkbox" /> This is checkbox <br />
      <input type="checkbox" /> This is checkbox <br />
      <input type="checkbox" /> This is checkbox <br />
      <input type="checkbox" /> This is checkbox <br />
      <input type="checkbox" /> This is checkbox <br />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

looks like this :

[image]

Comment: Please update the snippet we made you into a [mcve] - you do not have a containerSelectBox  in the HTML

Comment: i think you can  use scrollspy of bootstrap 
 
link is here  https://www.quackit.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_3/tutorial/bootstrap_scrollspy.cfm